# Postfix/Dovecot: Relay access denied

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-12.04, dovecot

I've installed `postfix` and `dovecot-imadp`. Connecting using thunderbird works fine, but when I try to send an email I get the following error: `5.7.1 <receiver@example.com>: Relay access denied`. What can I do to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'll be the `mynetworks` directive in the main.cf configuration file for postfix.

See [this question.](https://serverfault.com/questions/371691/how-do-i-configure-postfix-to-allow-other-machines-to-send-out-email-through-it)

Comment: Thank you! If someone else has this problem: `mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128, 0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: Making the whole internet a trusted network will get your server blacklisted in no time. An open relay like this is likely to be used by spammers.